# Blend multiple shapes.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Using [circle and square equations](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2hicifir6k) I was able to draw [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbglu.png). Any way to blend these two shapes(equations) like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aURFk.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zaP4.png). I want to achieve [metaballs](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Metaballs) like effect.

[image]

[image]

I'm using unity engine to render the above, I want a 2D version of it. I basically colored all pixels which are inside a circle.
Eg: using unit circle at origin equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ I'm coloring all pixels if $p_x^2 + p_y^2 <= 1$, where $p_x$ and $p_y$ are position of pixel.So I want a equation(or method) which blends the shapes and determines if a pixel is inside the overall shape.

Comment: What is a metaball ?

Comment: Your question is too general. You should be more explicit about 1) The software you use. Do you want to stay with Desmos, switch to Geogebra or another software ? 2) Whether you want, out of a set of 2D points generate a of 3D points mesh, with for example which kind of lighting (are you familiar with Gouraud, Phong ?...)

Comment: Do you want the result have the appearance of a stamp or a stamping device  ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I want 2d points. No lightings. I'm using unity and desmos. Just want a equation. I draw circle by coloring a pixel at (px,py) if (x - px)^2 + (y - py)^2 < radius^2.

Comment: @JeanMarie My result is bit complicated. I use many types of shapes. I was able to draw them using its respective 2d equations. I just want to blend them together.

Comment: Now that you show your animation, it has become a very different question ... I doubt that you can do what you want remaining in 2D. You will have to work in 3D and project the scene...

Comment: Could you add the details of the software in the post so it has the maximum chance of being re-opened @HelloHumans

Comment: @Aplateofmomos Is my edit sufficient?

Comment: I've voted to open already. and posted a meta thread here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34839/should-more-ambiguous-problem-be-allowed. Hopefully there is some community support to open it. You yourself can cast one open vote I think

Comment: @Aplateofmomos your efforts to reopen have paid off!

Comment: I was just thinking about this question, and it sort reminds me of how the orbitals of elements in chemistry mix together to form new hybridized ones. Maybe you could build off this a bit more? Search up "Hybridization of orbitals" if you haven't learned it already

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got working pseudocode:

```
//distance between point p and circle with radius r
float sdCircle( vec2 p, float r )
{
    return length(p) - r;
}

//function to blend
float smin( float a, float b, float k )
{
    float res = exp2( -k*a ) + exp2( -k*b );
    return -log2( res )/k;
}

float circle1_Dis = sdCircle(...);
float circle2_Dis = sdCircle(...);
float k = 0.5; // how much to blend

if(smin(circle1_Dis ,circle2_Dis ,k) < 0)
{
    //draw
}
```

reference:

- https://iquilezles.org/articles/distfunctions2d/
- https://iquilezles.org/articles/smin/
- https://youtu.be/Cp5WWtMoeKg

[image]

Comment: You use the (binary) log of the sum of 2 negative exponential to express the distance function ; interesting, I had never seen that before...

Comment: You will be possibly interested by this Wikipedia article on ["LogSumExp"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp) where the geometrical "blending" you use has a correspondence in the domain of deep learning

Comment: @JeanMarie It's amazing that such simple functions are used in diverse fields.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Geogebra figure (sorry, I don't use that much Desmos) I just made in order to convey the two main ideas :

- 1. **An angular parametrization** of the circle **and as well** of the square by an **angle** in the range $[0, 2 \pi)$. For the circle, it is the very natural :

$$N=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$$

with an added horizontal shift as you have done.

For the square, you have to divide the previous expression by a tuned quantity shrinking the circle into the square by a certain factor depending on the angle $t$ ; this quantity can be given the closed form $\max(|\cos(t)|,|\sin(t)|)$ explaining coordinates:

$$M=N/\max(|\cos(t)|,|\sin(t)|)$$

- 2. Intermediate moving point generating the level line labelled $s$ with $0 \le s \le 1$ given by barycentric expression

$$P=(1-s)M+sN$$

(for example if $s=\frac12$, you get the midpoint of line segment $MN$ ; the smallest $s$, the closer you are to point $M$, etc.).

You see that the locus of point $P$ gives one (among many) intermediate shapes between the square and the circle.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this approach produces third intermediate shape P. I want M and N to slowly blend together like metaballs. I have updated my question to make it clear.

Comment: Yes but what I have displayed is a "didactic" example for a particular values of $s$ ; make $s$ vary now.